# float/double equality with exact zero

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have an algorithm which uses `floats` or `doubles` to perform some calculations.

Example:

```
double a;
double b;
double c;
...
double result = c / (b - a);
if ((result > 0) && (result < small_number))
{
    // result is relevant...
} else {
    // result not required...
}
```

Now, I am worried about `(b - a)` might be zero. If it is close to zero but not zero, it does not matter because the `result` will be out of range to be useful, and I already detect that (as `(b - a)` approaches zero, `result` will approach +/- inf, which is not in the range `0`-`small_number`...)

But if the result of `(b  - a)` is exactly zero, I expect that something platform dependant will happen due to divide by zero. I could change the `if` statement to:

```
if ((!((b-a) == 0.0)) && ((result = c/(b-a)) > 0) && (result < small_number)) {
```

but I don't know if `(b-a) == 0.0` will always detect equality with zero. I have seen there are multiple representations for exact zero in floating point? How can you test for them all without doing some epsilon check, which I don't need (a small epsilon will be ignored in my algorithm)?

What is the platform independant way to check?

**EDIT:**

Not sure if it was clear enough to people. Basically I want to know how to find if an expression like:

```
double result = numerator / denominator;
```

will result in a floating point exception, a cpu exception, a signal from the operating system or something else.... without actually performing the operating and seeing if it will "throw"... because detecting a "throw" of this nature seems to be complicated and platform specific.

Is `( (denominator==0.0) || (denominator==-0.0) ) ? "Will 'throw'" : "Won't 'throw'";` enough?

Comment: Even if `b - a` isn't exactly zero, the operation `c / (b - a)` could still overflow and send the value to `+/-INF`.

Comment: @Mystical That's fine, it would put the result outside of the range of interest for my problem.

Comment: It's hard to find an implementation that doesn't use IEEE floating-point. So I think it's safe to assume that division by `0` will just yield `+INF` or `-INF`? Someone care to correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @Mysticial: Depends on what the numerator is. Apparently `0.0 / 0.0` is NaN, and triggers a different FP exception when exceptions are enabled.

Comment: Ah, good point. I didn't think about that - especially the `0.0 / 0.0` case.

Comment: BTW, Mystical is partially correct. gcc will simply do a segmentation fault, which is (I believe) an un-catchable exception. At any rate, Division by zero should never be a caught exception. I think this is an excellent question and IMHO, any person writing a division operator should always test for zero regardless of the code

Comment: Try rearranging the condition so that you're dividing by `small_number` instead of `b-a`.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on how `b` and `a` got their values.   Zero has an exact representation in floating point format, but the bigger problem would be almost-but-not-quite zero values.  It would always be safe to check:

```
if (abs(b-a) > 0.00000001  && ...
```

Where 0.00000001 is whatever value makes sense.

Comment: Why exactly would an almost-but-not-quite zero number be a problem? My algorithm already rejects results from a almost-but-not-quite zero denominator...

Comment: @Bingo:  I don't see your algorithm rejecting `b - a` with a value of `1e-300`.  Such a test costs little and is great insurance for resisting morphing of code, even if one version of it cannot produce that value.

Comment: the point is that anything divided by nearly zero is large... outside the range of `0` to `small_number` which is the range I am interested in.

Comment: Shouldn't that be fabs instead of abs?

Comment: @warl0ck:  if you want to use the function version, that would be okay.  However, there is the macro/template version `abs()` which works with all scalar types.

Comment: This answer helped me in my search. Was dubious about abs vs. fabs and in gcc, abs works on all scalar types (I tested it on qreal and glFloat as well.)  My own two cents are inlining the test with a ternary (As long as you're the maintainer or you comment a lot) `double result = c / ((abs((b - a)) > 0.00000001f) ? (b - a) : 0.00000001f) ;` That expression is, however, ugly as sin.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how you do it: instead of checking for `(result < small_number)`, you check for

```
(abs(c) < abs(b - a) * small_number)
```

Then all your troubles disappear! The computation of `c/(b-a)` will never overflow if this test is passed.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can use [`fpclassify(-0.0) == FP_ZERO`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fpclassify) . But this is only useful if you want to check if someone did put some kind of zero into float-type variable. As many already said if you want to check result of calculation you may get values very close to zero due to nature of representation.

Comment: Please comment a reason for downvoting. I promise that's only for understanding my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

**In brief, we can know a floating number is ZERO exactly if we know it represent format.**

---

**In practice**, we compare `x` with a small number. And if `x` is less than this number, we think `x` is as same as ZERO functionally (but most of time our small number is still large than zero). This method is very easy, efficient and can cross platform.

---

**Actually**, the `float` and `double` have been presented by special format, and the widely used one is [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)  in current hardware which divided the number into sign, exponent and mantissa (significand) bits.

So, if we want to check if a float number is **ZERO** exactly, we can check if both exponent and mantissa is ZERO, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand).

> In IEEE 754 binary floating point numbers, zero values are represented
>   by the biased exponent and significand both being zero. Negative zero
>   has the sign bit set to one.

Take `float` for example, we can write a simple code to extract exponent and mantissa bit and then check it.

```
#include <stdio.h>   

typedef union {
          float f;
          struct {
              unsigned int mantissa : 23;
              unsigned int exponent : 8;
              unsigned int sign :     1;
          } parts;
} float_cast;


int isZero(float num) {

    int flag = 0;
    float_cast data;
    data.f = num;

    // Check both exponent and mantissa parts
    if(data.parts.exponent == 0u && data.parts.mantissa == 0u) {
       flag = 1;
    } else {
       flag = 0;
   }

   return(flag);
}


int main() {

   float num1 = 0.f, num2 = -0.f, num3 = 1.2f;

   printf("\n is zero of %f -> %d", num1, isZero(num1));
   printf("\n is zero of %f -> %d", num2, isZero(num2));
   printf("\n is zero of %f -> %d", num3, isZero(num3));

   return(0);
}
```

Test results:

> # is zero of 0.000000  -> 1
>    # is zero of -0.000000 -> 1
>    # is zero of 1.200000  -> 0

---

**More examples:**

Let's check when the `float` becomes real ZERO with code.

```
void test() {
     int i =0;
     float e = 1.f, small = 1.f;
     for(i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
         e *= 10.f;
         small = 1.f/e;
         printf("\nis %e zero? : %d", small, isZero(small));
     }
     return;
}


is 1.0000e-01 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-02 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-03 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-04 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-05 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-06 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-07 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-08 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-09 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-10 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-11 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-12 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-13 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-14 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-15 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-16 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-17 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-18 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-19 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-20 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-21 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-22 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-23 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-24 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-25 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-26 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-27 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-28 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-29 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-30 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-31 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-32 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-33 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-34 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-35 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-36 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-37 zero? : NO
is 1.0000e-38 zero? : NO
is 0.0000e+00 zero? : YES   <-- 1e-39
is 0.0000e+00 zero? : YES   <-- 1e-40
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE (2016-01-04)

I've received some downvotes on this answer, and I wondered if I should just delete it.  It seems the consensus (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146403/should-i-delete-my-answers) is that deleting answers should only be done in extreme cases.

So, my answer is wrong.  But I guess I'm leaving it up because it provides for an interesting "think out of the box" kind of thought experiment.

===============

Bingo,

You say you want to know if b-a == 0.

Another way of looking at this is to determine whether a == b.  If a equals b, then b-a will be equal 0.

Another interesting idea I found:

http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/Comparing%20floating%20point%20numbers.htm

Essentially, you take the floating point variables you have and tell the compiler to reinterpret them (bit for bit) as signed integers, as in the following:

```
if (*(int*)&b == *(int*)&a)
```

Then you are comparing integers, and not floating points.  Maybe that will help?  Maybe not.  Good luck!

Comment: I'd upvote this if it weren't for the rather ugly casting thing.  `if (a!=b) { /* do the math */ }` is good enough for this case; anything else is overkill.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The equality idea is worth thinking about. Would be nice for a more general solution when the denominator wasn't the result of a subtraction though. Also, I think comparing bitwise (which is the integer approach) is the problem here. Different representations of zero would have different bit patterns anyway.

Comment: Not only `*(int*)&b == *(int*)&a` breaks strict aliasing rules, but it makes `+0.` appear different from `-0.`. I do not see any point to using this comparison here.

Comment: Even worse, on nearly all platforms, `int` is 32 bits and `double` 64, so you're just comparing the high or low (depending on your platform) 32 bits for equality, which is useless. (Plus, it would compare two NaNs as equal if they happen to have the same bits set, and unequal if they don't, which is definitely not useful…)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `(b-a)==0` will be true exactly in those cases when the `c/(b-a)` would fail because of `(b-a)` being zero. The float maths is tricky but questioning this is exaggerating in my opinion. Also I believe that the `(b-a)==0` is going to be equivalent to `b!=a`.

Distinguishing positive and negative 0 is also not necessary. See e.g. here [Does float have a negative zero? (-0f)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095968/does-float-have-a-negative-zero-0f)

Comment: Regarding “the order of evaluation of the sub-expressions in your condition is not defined in c++”, in `e1 && e2`, the order of evaluation **is** defined. `e2` is always evaluated after `e1` and only if `e1` evaluates to true/nonzero.

Comment: You're right! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112282/order-of-evaluation-of-operands I will delete that part. Rest of the answer I leave although the deleted part was why I decided to reply...

Comment: Dividing with floating point zero is well defined if the compiler follows IEEE standards. [Read more on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617408/a-few-things-about-division-by-zero-in-c) or read [the IEEE floating point standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero#In_computer_arithmetic)!

Answer (score 0):

For epsilon, in  there is a standard template definition std::numeric_limits::epsilon(). I guess checking the difference to be bigger than std::numeric_limits::epsilon() should be safe enough to protect against division by zero. No platform dependency here I guess.

Comment: This answer is nonsense. `std::numeric_limits::epsilon()` is not intended for this usage, it measures the ULP just above `1.0`. And when dividing by `x`, division by zero only occurs when `x == 0` (overflow can occur, but this has already been pointed out).

Comment: Right, it is not an answer to the original problem, just a remark related to epsilon. I should have put it in as a comment, but many previous posts referred to this. But your remark is correct. More on this [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon]

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```
if ((b-a)!=(a-b) && ((result = c/(b-a)) > 0) && (result < small_number))) {
...
```

Comment: Not exactly sure, but are you sure that `(b-a)` and `(a-b)` would produce the same version of zero in floating point?