# Modulus with floating point in c

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, floating-point-conversion

I'm getting illegal use of floating point error on compiling the following program. Please let me know where I am committing a mistake.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    float a;
    clrscr();
    printf("\n Enter the num : ");
    scanf("%f", &a);

    if ( a >= 0 )
    {
        if ( (a % 2) == 0 ) //ERROR HERE
        {
            printf("\n You entered a positive even num");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n You entered a positive odd num");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ( (a % 2) == 0 ) //ERROR HERE
        {
            printf("\n You entered a negative even num");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n You entered a negative odd num");
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `%` is for integer types.  Use [`fmod()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod).

But as usual, be very wary of [performing equality comparisons (`==`) with floating-point types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542391/float-double-equality-with-exact-zero).  Perhaps in your case it would be better to work with integer types throughout.

Comment: ... or better change `a` to be an `int` (if you are reasoning about odd/even, you are perhaps working with an integer anyway).

Comment: what parameters to be passed in fmod() function.

Comment: @rippy: I've now added a link to some documentation.