# How to print all integers which satisfy an equation?

Tags: c++

I need to write a program in C++ which prints all of the numbers between -50 and 0 that satisfy the equation: 18^3-18x^2+6=0

My if statement doesn't seem to return any results, it should :(

I think I'm along the right lines....

```
for (int x = -50; x < 0; x++) {
    int y = pow(x, 3) - 18 * pow(x,3) + 6;
    if(y == 0)
        cout << y << endl;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Run it through a debugger.

Comment: What result should it return? (Also, your expression has 18x ^ **2**, but your code has 18 * pow(x, **3**) -- not the same).

Comment: In your code you have `y = x³ - 18x³ + 6 = -17x³ + 6`. The roots of this polynominal are the third roots of `6/17`, none of which is integral.

Answer (score 3):

[Your equation doesn't have any integer roots.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=18*x%5E3-18*x%5E2%2B6%3D0)

It simplifies to: `3*(x+1)*(x-1)*x = -1`. The integers dividing `-1` are `1` and `-1`, so there is no integer solution to your equation.

Answer (score 0):

Three errors:

1. If you want to include 0, use x<=0 instead of x<0
2. your function was wrong, pow(x,2) instead of pow(x,3)
3. you should output x not y, otherwise you'll only output zero

   ```
   for(int x=-50;x<=0;x++){
       int y=pow(x,3)-18*pow(x,2)+6;
       if(y==0)
         cout << x << endl;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `double` type for your variable `y` because the equation has no integer roots. However never check a double variable equal zero. This may [help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542391/float-double-equality-with-exact-zero)

Comment: Surely an integer type would be a better choice to represent an integer?

Comment: To calculate the result you need double because the equation has no integer roots. After that the result could be casted to integer if this is explicit wanted.

Comment: The fact that the equation has no integer roots means there's no integer value of `x` for which `y==0`. I.e. you would need to make `x` double too. And then the next problem is that neither `x++` nor `x=x+1.0` works to find that root.

Comment: @MSalters Yes you are right. I have overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation in question and in code are different:

I think it should be this

```
for (int x = -50; x < 0; x++) {
   int y = pow(x, 3) - 18 * pow(x,2) + 6;
   if(y == 0)
       cout << y << endl;
```

}

And also check if equation provided is correct or not