# What is the best solution to calculate and store maximum values using the GPU? My current one is not satisfactory

Tags: algorithm, cuda

I have the following kernel that runs on my device:

```
__global__ void kernel1(float *Vb, int *sS, int *sE, int *bI, float *eR, int S, int K, int B, int N)
{
    const unsigned long long int blockId = blockIdx.x //1D
        + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x //2D
        + gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z; //3D
    const unsigned long long int threadId = blockId * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int s = threadId / (K * B), k = (threadId - (s * K * B)) / B, b = threadId - (s * K * B) - (k * B);

    if (s < S && k < K && b < B)
    {
        float sum = 0;

        for (int t = sS[k]; t <= sE[k]; t++)
            sum += eR[s * N + bI[b * N + t]];

        if (sum > Vb[b * K + k])
        {
            Vb[b * K + k] = sum;
        }
    }
}
```

I basically calculate some sums based on the eR[SxN] and bI[BxN] matrices (that are mapped as simple 1D arrays) and on the sE[K] and sS[K] arrays, and try to store the maximum value obtained for each (s,(k,b)) pair in the Vb[BxK] matrix (that is also mapped as an 1D array).

The problem that I have is that in the end, the Vb matrix does not contain the maximum values calculated for each pair. From what I can figure out, the problem arises because all GPU threads run in parallel (which is, of course, a good thing) and they all reach the "if (sum > Vb[b * K + k])" statement at the same time, thus all evaluating the Vb[b * K + k] element based on it's original value. Because of this, the final value stored in Vb[b * K + k] is the value of the sum calculated in the last thread that set the value of the element (last sum larger than the original element value), and not the overall maximum.

In order to correct for this I tried transforming Vb into a [SxKxB] cube in order to calculate the sums for all (s,k,b) pairs and then maxing out the elements for each s on the CPU. The kernel looks like this:

```
__global__ void kernel2(float *Vb, int *sS, int *sE, int *bI, float *eR, int S, int K, int B, int N)
{
    const unsigned long long int blockId = blockIdx.x //1D
        + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x //2D
        + gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z; //3D
    const unsigned long long int threadId = blockId * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int s = threadId / (K * B), k = (threadId - (s * K * B)) / B, b = threadId - (s * K * B) - (k * B);

    if (s < S && k < K && b < B)
    {
        float sum = 0;

        for (int t = sS[k]; t <= sE[k]; t++)
            sum += eR[s * N + bI[b * N + t]];

        Vb[s * K * B + k * B + b] = sum;
    }
}
```

This works fine for relatively small S, K and B's, but when these are large (say S = 100000, K = 12, B = 1000), the memory requirements of the Vb matrix (about 4.5GB) far exceeds the device free memory (about 600-700MB).

So my questions are: 
1. is there any way to make the first kernel work as expected (in the end obtaining the max sum)?
2. what do you think is the best approach for this problem when working with large sets of data? 
a. splitting up the data into multiple chunks and running multiple instances of kernel2? (I think this dramatically increases the time necessary for the calculations)
b. investing in hardware with larger memory capabilities? 
c. I have read that there is the possibility of directly using the host memory from the device (with zero-memory copy) but I am not familiar with how it works right now. Might this be a solution? (so I can focus on learning and implementing it)
d. another approach (please suggest)...the simpler the better.

A positive and efficient solution to the first question would be much preferred.

My device is a GeForce GT 220 with 1GB total memory and compute capability 1.2 (latest driver). I am using CUDA5.5 in VS2012 on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement and use a float version of `atomicMax()` but performance may not be good -- especially on a CC 1.2 device. Might be worth a try though.

Borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17401122/442006:

```
__device__ static float atomicMax(float* address, float val)
{
    int* address_as_i = (int*) address;
    int old = *address_as_i, assumed;
    do {
        assumed = old;
        old = ::atomicCAS(address_as_i, assumed,
            __float_as_int(::fmaxf(val, __int_as_float(assumed))));
    } while (assumed != old);
    return __int_as_float(old);
}
```

Then:

```
__global__ void kernel1(float *Vb, int *sS, int *sE, int *bI, float *eR, int S, int K, int B, int N)
{
    const unsigned long long int blockId = blockIdx.x //1D
        + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x //2D
        + gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z; //3D
    const unsigned long long int threadId = blockId * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int s = threadId / (K * B), k = (threadId - (s * K * B)) / B, b = threadId - (s * K * B) - (k * B);

    if (s < S && k < K && b < B)
    {
        float sum = 0;

        for (int t = sS[k]; t <= sE[k]; t++)
            sum += eR[s * N + bI[b * N + t]];

        atomicMax(Vb + b * K + k, sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Atomics is the answer for me. It seems that the extra overhead introduced by using atomicMax was compensated by the more efficient processing on the CPU side due to the reduced size of the data matrix. Thank you very much.