# Can anybody help me with atomicmin function syntax for cuda?

Tags: cuda, gpu, atomic, minimum, double-compare-and-swap

I am unable to get a proper syntax for using `atomicMin`. I would like to use this function to operate on double rather than integer.

```
__global__ void npd(int *a, int *g)         
    {   
        int index = threadIdx.x;

        __shared__ int d[N];

        d[threadIdx.x]=a[index];        

        __syncthreads();        

        int dd;
        int inn;
        int u;

        if( 0==threadIdx.x )
        { 
            for( int u = 0; u<16; u++ )
            {
                atomicMin( g, d ) ;     
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is none inbuilt, but there are some nifty tricks you can use to create your own: http://stereopsis.com/radix.html

Comment: This Devtalk forum post seems to give a solution, I haven't tested it, give it a go : https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/492068/atomicmin-with-float/

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicmin -- the documentation clearly says there is no atomicMin for any floating point types, single or double

Comment: @talonmies I assume the question is less literal than what you answer. OP may know it does not exists, and is asking for help on how to implement it.

Comment: Asking for "proper syntax" sure doesn't sound like it.....

Answer (score 1):

The `atomicMin` function [defined by CUDA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicmin) doesn't support use with floating-point quantities.  Referring to the documentation, we see that the only available prototypes are for `int`, `unsigned int`, and `unsigned long long int` (the last requiring compiling for, and running on, a GPU of compute capability 3.5 or higher).

There are at least 2 options.

1. You could refactor your code to replace atomics with a [classical parallel reduction](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf).
2. As indicated in [the programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions), "arbitrary" atomics can be created using `atomicCAS` (compare-and-swap) plus a loop of some sort.

Here's one possible realization, for `double`:

```
__device__ double atomicMin_double(double* address, double val)
{
    unsigned long long int* address_as_ull = (unsigned long long int*) address;
    unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;
    do {
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed,
            __double_as_longlong(fmin(val, __longlong_as_double(assumed))));
    } while (assumed != old);
    return __longlong_as_double(old);
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399119/cant-we-use-atomic-operations-for-floating-point-variables-in-cuda) related question and answers may also be of interest, although it primarily has `float` in view.

A few other comments:

- by switching to `float` instead of `double` I believe it is possible to simplify the `atomicMin` (or `atomicMax`) operation as indicated in the answer I linked to above, probably with a few caveats (e.g. no NaN, INF data, for example).  I believe that iee754 `float` follows an ordering rule for two quantities `A` and `B` such that if `A > B`, then `*reinterpret_cast<int*>(&A) > *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&B)`.  I'm not sure `double` follows a similar rule with `long long` (probably someone else will be able to say).
- in your code, this loop could operate on a local quantity first, then do a single atomic operation at the end, like so:

  ```
      double v = *g;
      for( int u = 0; u<16; u++ )
      {
          v = min(v,d);     
      }
      atomicMin_double(g, v);
  ```

  which I think should be faster