# float number range in php. -0 is float?

Tags: php, numbers, floating

when I'm converting string `'-0'`in float it returns float type `-0`

example

```
$x = '-0';
$y = (float)$x;
```

result => float -0

why `-0` is float number ?

Comment: You are explicitly casting it to `(float)`, are you not?

Comment: in my mind -0 can not be float value ...

Comment: you are casting it to float. and asking why it is float now.

Comment: *Why* can it not be a float value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IEEE 754 standard, which is how almost all computer languages implement floating point numbers, has both a `+0` and a `-0` value.

For most operations, `+0` and `-0` can be used interchangeably.

However, operations that error out to infinity, use `+0` or `-0` to go to +Infinity and -Infinity.

Because `-0` is a valid floating point number, it makes perfect sense that casting `-0` to a float would do exactly as you asked --- returning a floating point number with a value of exactly `-0`.

Comment: what is different between -0 and +0 ? what will output if(-0 == +0) TRUE or FALSE ?

Comment: @Anri - 30 seconds with PHP would answer that question faster than it takes to ask it here.

Comment: They are equal. "PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format" - Read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095968/does-float-have-a-negative-zero-0f

Answer (score 0):

We all know that all integers are floats. And in PHP from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

> Integers can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), octal (base 8) or binary (base 2) notation, optionally preceded by a sign (- or +)

So `-0` is an `int` which is normally a `float`