# What is the difference between 0 and -0 floating point value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, floating-point

This code snippet in Visual Studio 2013:

```
double a = 0.0;
double b = -0.0;

cout << (a == b) << " " << a << " " << b;
```

prints `1 0 -0`. What is the difference between `a` and `b`?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Comment: The difference is either `0` or `-0`

Comment: Dear downvoters, I tried googling it, unfortunately my query `float -0 0` was treated too literally. `float "-0" 0` works much better. Just in case someone else itches to downvote.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks, I meant `a` and `b`.

Comment: [*"floating point negative zero"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=floating+point+negative+zero) makes an even better search queue. The top hit is a Wikipedia article on [signed zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero), probably a good read. The matter is not limited to C++, much less Visual Studio. It is an IEEE standard for floating point values.

Comment: Also related: [Does float have a negative zero? (-0f)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095968/does-float-have-a-negative-zero-0f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ does not guarantee to differentiate between +0 and -0. This is a feature of each particular number representation. The IEEE 754 standard for floating point arithmetic does make this distinction, which can be used to keep sign information even when numbers go to zero. `std::numeric_limits` does not directly tell you if you have possible signed zeroes. But if `std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559` is true then you can in practice assume that you have IEEE 754 *representation*, and thus possibly negative zero.

---

Noted by “gmch” in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277539/what-is-the-difference-between-0-and-0-floating-point-value/25277641#comment39398277_25277641), the C++11 standard library way to check the sign of a zero is to use [`std::copysign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/copysign), or more directly using [`std::signbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit), e.g. as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>       // copysign, signbit

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    double const z1 = +0.0;
    double const z2 = -0.0;

    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << "z1 is " << (signbit( z1 )? "negative" : "positive") << "." << endl;
    cout << "z2 is " << (signbit( z2 )? "negative" : "positive") << "." << endl;
}
```

---

Without `copysign` or `signbit`, e.g. for a C++03 compiler, one way to detect a negative zero `z` is to check whether `1.0/z` is negative infinity, e.g. by checking if it's just negative.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    double const z1 = +0.0;
    double const z2 = -0.0;

    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << "z1 is " << (1/z1 < 0? "negative" : "positive") << "." << endl;
    cout << "z2 is " << (1/z2 < 0? "negative" : "positive") << "." << endl;
}
```

But while this will probably work in practice on most any implementation, it's formally <sup>*</sup>Undefined Behavior.

One needs to be sure that the expression evaluation will not trap.

---

<sup><sup>*)</sup> C++11 §5.6/4 “If the second operand of `/` or `%` is zero the behavior is undefined”</sup>

Comment: `copysign(1.0, x)` is a less brutal way of discovering whether `x` is -0 or 0.

Comment: @gmch: Thanks, I'd forgotten `copysign`. Never used it.

Answer (score 2):

See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

In a nutshell, it is due to the sign being stored as a stand-alone bit in IEEE 754 floating point representation. This leads to being able to have a zero exponent and fractional portions but still have the sign bit set--thus a negative zero. This is a condition that wouldn't happen for signed integers which are stored in twos-complement.

Comment: Signed integers may be stored in one's complement or sign-magnitude, which has negative zero.

Comment: @MattMcNabb is technically correct. You might see ones complement used on older mainframe and minis from three decades ago or so. There is some good history about it here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations