# Why floating ZERO in Java can be either positive or negative?

Tags: java, android

I have a code

```
private float roundAwayFrom0(float value) {
    float abs = Math.abs(value);
    float sign = (value == 0) ? 1 : value / (abs);
    return (sign * (Math.round(abs)));
}
```

And when 
**sign = -1f**
and 
**Math.round(abs) = 0**

I have expected that result should be `0.0f`
But the actual is `-0.0f`. What the magic?

Comment: Apart from the actual answer. With a leading `-` you know you reached the zero from a negative starting point.

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you to understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095968/does-float-have-a-negative-zero-0f

Comment: @Kevinrob thanks! Yep.

Comment: A user of your experience could know that "prior research" is expected prior asking a question. It took me 2 seconds to find that dup - I am sure it took you more than 2 seconds to write up this question ...