# Strange behavior with negative numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a negative number, e.g. -0.0024574302611661907
I want to do round on it, supposed to get 0

But I get "-0"
Math.round(num) --> -0

Why does it behave like this?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095968/does-float-have-a-negative-zero-0f

Comment: You can or with zero to get rid of `-0`: `Math.round(-0.1)||0`