# Matlab division by 0: Inf or -Inf

Tags: matlab, division, infinite, zero, divide-by-zero

I cannot figure out why division by 0 gives different results in the following two cases.
`amort` is a function that calculates a constant amortization schedule. The only thing we care about now is that the last element of A is exactly 0.

```
amort = @(r,M) ((1+r).^(0:M)' - (1+r).^M) ./ (1-(1+r).^M)

A = amort(0.03, 20);

>> A(end)==0
ans =
     1
```

What looks strange is the following:

```
>> 1/0
ans =
   Inf
>> 1/A(end)
ans =
  -Inf
```

However

```
>> sign(A(end))
ans =
     0
>> 1/abs(A(end))
ans =
   Inf
```

How is this possible and why? Is there some kind of hidden "sign"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Gnu Octave have negative zeroes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109755/why-does-gnu-octave-have-negative-zeroes)

Comment: While the duplicate references Octave, the accepted answer deals with MATLAB and the IEEE-754 format.

Comment: `A(end)` is negative zero. `fprintf('%f\n', A(end))` returns `-0.000000`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`A(end)` actually has it's sign bit set (i.e. it is negative zero). Try using [`num2hex`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2hex.html) to see the hex representation:

```
>> a = -0
a =
     0    % Note the sign isn't displayed

>> num2hex(A(end))
ans =
8000000000000000

>> num2hex(a)
ans =
8000000000000000  % Same as above

>> num2hex(0)
ans =
0000000000000000  % All zeroes

>> 1/a
ans =
  -Inf
```

Notice that a `-0` is displayed as `0`, but in reality has its sign bit set. Hence the `-Inf` result.

Also note this explanation of the [`sign`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sign.html) function (emphasis mine):

> For each element of X, sign(X) returns 1 if the element
>       is greater than zero, 0 if it equals zero and **-1 if it is
>       less than zero**.

Since `-0` isn't less than zero, but instead equal to `0`, `sign` returns `0`.

Comment: I see - this is useful. Any guess why the sign bit is set to zero then? Does it depend on machine precision/approximation in performing the calculations requested by `amort` ? Can I prevent these situations?

Comment: @Giuseppe: In the `amort` function in your example, the numerator for the last vector element will be 0 but the denominator will be `(1-1.03^20)`, or about -0.8061. Dividing 0 by a negative number gives you -0. If you swap the terms in both the numerator and denominator (i.e. multiply through by -1 on top and bottom) you can avoid it.